# Do minecart puzzles like this, with buttons that rotate track, exist?

Tags: puzzle-creation, puzzle-identification

This is the end result of me messing around with minecarts and moving floors.

[image: Minecraft screenshot]

The buttons change the orientation of either their nearest or their same-color track. Now I'm not asking you to solve the puzzle, but if you want to, the green buttons are linked, and you can cross the orange rock block.

Does this puzzle type have a name? I'm almost certain they exist, maybe in a grid-based game using trains instead. And how do I make these puzzles engaging?

Comment: By "how do I create these puzzles" do you mean the physical act of creating them, or the creative act of designing them?

Comment: Heya!  This is an in interesting question that I am happy to provide a fuller answer to how I create them later... but if you are looking for a quick answer to the first half, I believe they are just a special type of "maze" that I have heard called a "stateful maze".

Comment: Hosting images on our dedicated site i.stack.imgur.com is preferable (long-lasting, ad-free, etc), so I moved your screenshot there.

Comment: This is old now, but a good place to look: http://clickmazes.com/